# Was the post-rebellion Madoka still a Magical Girl?

Tags: madoka-magica

### **Unmarked Spoilers**

Since Homura separated "the Madoka that was before attaining divinity" from the Law of Cycles, is the Madoka post-rebellion a Mahou Shoujo?

I'm talking about the Madoka that shows up as the "transfer student" at the end of rebelllion. And being a magical girl in that context means having one's soul in a soul gem.

Comment: Good question. The movie was pretty unclear about how the split between Madoka as a person and the immutable Law of Cycles worked, at least from what I remember. I do believe it was implied that Homura was the only magical girl left in the universe she created, and that she had reshaped the nature of a magical girl into a being who collects curse energy and funnels it into Kyuubei. Then again, it was also implied that Madoka and Sayaka regaining their memories could somehow endanger the existence of that universe, which seems bizarre if they had become completely normal humans again.

Comment: i would answer this but even i am not confident to make a speculation on this. we know that Homura "sealed" Sayaka's abilities as a Magical Girl/Witch and i do believe that all the other Magical Girls have had their powers sealed so they can live normal lives. but it's hard to tell what Homura did with Madoka. in the one hand she could have done the same to Madoka as she did to Sayaka but then Madoka is still technically a God (something beyond a Magical Girl like Homura). on the other hand this could be just the human aspect of Madoka that still cared for Homura to risk the Incubator's trap

Comment: @Torisuda my impression was that Homura just made the Incubators embody the curses similar to what Wraiths do, reducing the number of wraiths so that Magical Girls no longer need to fight. as for the endangerment of the existence of the universe i assumed what Sayaka was talking about was that it was the Incubtaors who were cycling the energy to contract entropy and now Homura have given them a new existence rather than erase them (remember she she said she'd keep them in her new universe to handle earth's curses, nothing said about the universe's energy)

Comment: (cont) and that the Law of Cycles is broken so Magical Girls could become Witches again

Comment: @Memor-X the only certainty I could get is that the incubators won't make any more magical girls, because they state they will never again meddle with humanity. Since the incubators never lie, that is a given.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure whether Madoka in God Mode is still a magical girl either. Did we ever see if she still has a soul gem? If God Mode Madoka isn't a magical girl, that would suggest that the version of her that Homura drags into the new universe isn't a magical girl either.